# How to install Ubuntu on Intel RST fake raid?

Tags: 16.10, raid, intel

I have got myself a new laptop with two 512GB NVMe M.2 SSD disks. It supports Intel RST, so I have set it up as a RAID 0 Array from Intel RST tool on Windows 10. Everything works good on Windows, but I also need Ubuntu so I have tried to Install it using the standard procedure.
However, Ubuntu doesn't see any of my disks, /dev/sd* doesn't exist, /dev/mapper is empty too.

Is this because hardware on my laptop (Alienware 13 R3 released in late 2016) is not yet supported?
Should I try more recent Kernel version - 4.10 instead of default 4.8?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I had similar issues even with the very latest Ubuntu kernel. I gave up on dual boot with Windows 10 on a Triton Predator and instead installed Oracle VirtualBox on the windows host. Ubuntu does seem slower in the VM, and usb device capture has been a pain, but it works.